# Preprocessor examples in C language

Tags: c++, c

I want some examples of C preprocessor directives, such as:

```
#define pi 3.14
#define MAX 100
```

I know only this.
I want to know more than this, more about preprocessor directives.

Comment: Your pi is woefully inaccurate.You might want to pull in M_PI from math.h.

Comment: This version of pi is much more accurate than the versions that nearly got passed into law in Indiana (not Kansas) about 100 years ago:  http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/805/did-a-state-legislature-once-pass-a-law-saying-pi-equals-3

Comment: A note on terminology, what you are calling "preprocessors" are more correctly called "preprocessor directives". The term "preprocessor" refers to a program that interprets preprocessor directives and modifies your source files accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The biggest example would be

```
 #include<stdio.h>
```

But there are a fair amount.  You can also define macros:

```
 #define MAX(X,Y) (((X) > (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))
```

And use [header guards](http://www.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/cs241/c241man/node90.html)

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

// code

#endif
```

There are proprietary extensions that compilers define to let you give processing directives:

```
#ifdef WIN32 // WIN32 is defined by all Windows 32 compilers, but not by others.
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

And the if statement cause also be used for commenting:

```
#if 0

int notrealcode = 0;

#endif
```

I often use the preprocessor to make debug builds:

```
#ifdef EBUG
printf("Debug Info");
#endif

$ gcc -DEBUG file.c //debug build
$ gcc file.c //normal build
```

And as everyone else has pointed out there are a lot of places to get more information:

- http://predef.sourceforge.net/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/

Comment: Always protect all arguments in macro expansions with parentheses.  Consider the expansion of '`MAX(x|3, y&4)`'; without parenthesizing '(X > Y)' as '((X) > (Y))', it doesn't evaluate to what you would expect.

Comment: Your header guard names are illegal.

Comment: What Neil is referring to is that in C (and C++) identifiers beginning with an underscore and capital letter are reserved for use by the OS and other elements of the language implementation.

Comment: @Tyler Certainly not reserved for the OS - for the C++ compiler and libraries.

Comment: @Neil so, all those headers in /usr/include/linux that define identifiers starting with an underscore and a capital letter are in violation of the C standard?

Comment: I've never seen that before (nor had a problem).  But I changed it for "good practices" purposes.

Comment: @Tyler: No. They are reserved for use by the implementation -- by system libraries and by the compiler. In other words, they are reserved *for* headers such as those under /usr/include/linux. That's the entire point. Those headers, being system headers, are allowed to use a special class of names, so that they can avoid naming conflicts with *your* code. So if *your* code starts using *their* names, that whole system falls apart, and you risk getting conflicts.

Comment: @jalf I understand the rationale behind reserving identifiers. I was taking issue with Neil nit-picking my comment that they're reserved for the OS in addition to the compiler, since obviously kernel headers use them and they're not part of the compiler (they're part of the kernel).

Comment: @Tyler The standard makes no mention of the operating system when it comes to reserved names, only the language implementation. If the files you refer to are part of the specific C or C++ implementation, then they are legal. If they come from elesewhere, like a whole raft of POSIX headers do, for excample, then they are not. Nothing new there, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

Are you entirely familiar with the fundamentals, e.g. as covered on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)?  Or do you need an elementary tutorial?  or what?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe one of

- [Wikipedia on C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)
- [GNU C preprocessor docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

can be of help.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot more to the processor than #define. Don't forget #include and conditional compilation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 2):

The most important one:

```
#ifndef THIS_HEADER_H
#define THIS_HEADER_H

// Declarations go here    

#endif //THIS_HEADER_H
```

This keeps a header file from being included in a single C file multiple times.

For gcc sources I like to use `__LINE__`, as in:

```
printf("%s: %d: Some debug info\n", __func__, __LINE__);
```

For debugging purposes.

Comment: Unless you are writing the compiler, you should avoid defining symbols starting with '_'.

Comment: Yup.  I fixed it to be more general.

Answer (score 1):

This will stop the compile if the conditional fails.

```
#define WIDTH 10
#define HEIGHT 20

#if WIDTH < HEIGHT
#    error "WIDTH must be greater than or equal to HEIGHT"
#endif
```

C Preprocessor Man pages
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html